# "The associated script cannot be loaded" error when I launch scene with .dll in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, dll, plugins

I have a project which has a scene and source files. One object in this scene uses one of the script from source files, and the scene works correctly. However, when I pack all sources from that project to .dll and add this .dll and the scene to a new project this script on scene's object will show error "The associated script cannot be loaded, please fix any compile errors and assign a valid script"
[image: Missing script error]

Next screenshot of structure for the project with sources
[image: Structure of working project]

And this one for the project where instead of source files I use .dll
[image: Not working project structure]

I'm trying to create plugin to Unity asset store with demo scene. How can I fix issue by reusing the scene in two different projects with same codebase but one is presented as source files and another as .dll?

Comment: Ensure the dll is compiled correctly. Use software like JetBrains dotPeak etc. Also check if error persists with another dll.

Comment: When you click on the DLL in your Project tab, does it show the behaviours you expect to see in there?  When you build your DLL, are you using a version of .NET that your version of Unity supports?  Are you referencing the correct UnityEngine.dll?

Comment: When I import DLL and scene to a new project I can re-assign script to the object from DLL. I use .net 4.8 for building DLL and I set in projects settings same requirements. I tried Unity version 2019 and 2021 and both have same issue. In both cases I build DLL with the right version of UnityEnfine.dll and UnityEditor.dll